# Map induced on the global sections by maps of projective varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X = \operatorname{Proj}( R[X,Y,Z]/(j))$ ( $j$ is a homogenous polynomial). Assume that $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{X }) = R$ form simplicity.

Suppose that there is a map of graded $R$-algebra $f:R[X,Y,Z]/(j) \to R[X,Y,Z]/(j)$ such that it induces a morphism of schemes $f:X \to X$ . Since $f$ is a morphism of scheme this means there should be an induced map from $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{X }) \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{X })$, i.e a map from $R \to R$.

How does one find out what is this induced map?

I think it will be identity because it is an $R$-algebra homomorphism.

(Edited the previous version of the question)

Comment: All functions on $\Bbb P^2_R$ are constant, and the induced map is the identity.

Comment: From the question, it is clear that you are not looking at an $R$-morphism $g$ (different use of $f$ is unfortunate, you have the homogeneous polynomial $f$ and a morphism $f$!). Then, you can take any morphism $g:R\to R$ so that $g(f)=f$ up to a unit. You can not say much more. The induced morphism will be $g:R\to R$.

Comment: I don't think the question is phrased properly. Basically, $f$ is given as a morphism of graded $R$ algebra. And I'm looking the morphism of scheme induced by $f$.